# tvOS - inputView on UITextfield does not work

Tags: uitextfield, tvos, custom-keyboard, inputview

Setting the inputView on the UITextField does not work. When the textfield is focused/selected it should show the inputView. Instead it does nothing, freezes and builds up memory usage slowly until it goes OOM and crashes.

Setting any view (empty UIView()) on a UITextField will reproduce the issue.

Tried on an AppleTV running tvOS 17.
And Simulator 16 and 17.

Here is a test project that shows cases the issue https://github.com/drs-st/test-tvos-custom-inputview/blob/develop/TestKeyboard/ViewController.swift

This issue has also been posted in Apple's developer Forum https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/745931.

Answer (score 0):

Apple confirmed that it's indeed not working via Apple’s Developer Technical Support.

> I'd like to confirm that `inputView` does not work on tvOS. I suggest that you file a feedback report to request the support if that is important to achieve your text input experience.